# Confused by past perfect

Tags: past-perfect

Which is more correct?

1."I was Photoshopping images long before digital cameras and computers had even been invented."

2."I had been Photoshopping images long before digital cameras and computers were even invented."

The past perfect is used for referring to an event earlier than the past, therefore I think 2. is correct (or maybe they're both wrong? ), can someone please help me?

Comment: "... digital cameras and computers was even invented" needs to be "**were** even invented" for number agreement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct, but you would only use the past perfect if you were talking about a situation or conversation in the past.

"He asked me if I knew how to use Photoshop. I told him that I had been Photoshopping images long before digital cameras were invented."

Comment: Why is 1. also grammatically correct? Shouldn't it be something like "I was Photoshopping images long before digital cameras and computers were even invented." (not 'had been')

Comment: Yes, that would be better. I was concentrating on the difference in tenses of the _first_ verb, as I thought that was what you were asking about.

Comment: Does this mean "I was Photoshopping images long before digital cameras and computers had even been invented." isn't really correct (strictly speaking) because "I was Photoshopping images long before digital cameras and computers were even invented." is 'better'?

Comment: I think both would work. At the time we are talking about, digital cameras _had not (yet) been invented_.